# jquery $.get() is not using https

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page that is loaded over HTTPS, and within the page I do an XHR request to a relative file, using jQuery $.get(), and according to Chrome, this is trying to fetch the request via HTTP, so I get a cross origin access control error loading.

How do I force my request to use HTTPS?

If this isn't clear, I'm loading https://example.com/myapp/ and in turn there is this JS:

```
$.get('file', function(data) { ... }
```

All JS files, including jQuery, are loaded over https. Amazingly, I can't find anything in jQuery docs related to the protocol of XHR. This cannot possibly be an edge case, seems like a very typical thing to do (load a relative URL over http via AJAX). Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried using an absolute URL (with HTTPS) to see if it works? Have you tried different URLs? Have you checked that the URL you're trying to fetch doesn't have some sort of redirect to the non-HTTPS version?

Comment: I agree with D. Strout's suggestion. Also, the link you provided gives a certificate error.  I'm not sure what jQuery/AJAX' response to a cert error would be, but that might be something to check.  I can tell you that AJAX over HTTPS works very well because I have many such calls in my apps.

Comment: @D.Strout Good question. Doing $.get('https: //mydomain/path/to/resource') works as expected, but makes my app completely unportable. $.get('/path/to/resource') uses HTTP (and also is not very portable). There are no redirects in play, as the first test shows. (edited to prevent SO making my url into a link)

Comment: @richb01 example.com is a fakish URL provided specifically for people to use as an example. I'm not providing the actual URL as this is an app I'm developing, not yet making public.

Comment: Did you read the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#HTTP_request and the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Well, I don't know what to suggest. I've never had this problem before; just yesterday I was working on some AJAX stuff over HTTPS with jQuery (POST not GET, have you tried seeing if that works?) and I had no problems - request was HTTPS just like I expected.

Comment: Have you tried on another browser?

Comment: Have you had it working with a relative URL path? I agree, this ought to just work, but I'm not doing anything fancy, just what I shared in my sample code. I'm wondering if it's a bug in jQuery (seems like it is by definition). I'm using jQuery 1.10.2 and jQuery Mobile 1.4.2. Hopefully the latter isn't mucking with jQuery internals, but worth mentioning.

Comment: @richb01 Same results in Safari. However I've solved the problem, will post an answer.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out this breaks:

```
$.get('directory', function(data) {...})
```

But this does not:

```
$.get('directory/', function(data) {...})
```

My sample code was misleading in using 'file' as the resource (I'd forgotten what I was fetching). So the first case is triggering a rewrite rule somewhere (the global Apache config which I don't have access to), and apparently that rewrite rule is not being smart about preserving the protocol. So the bug seems to lie with my hosting provider's Apache config, if it can be called a bug. To be clear, either one works in my app just fine if loaded over HTTP, so it is an actual bug that the rewrite breaks over HTTPS.

I doubt anyone will ever benefit from my question or answer, but if you're doing all of the above and have my same hosting provider, here it is!